# C# TFS get the last User that changed a specific File

Tags: c#, tfs

Based on a specific **file**'s location and name, I would like to use **C#** to programmatically get the name of the *last* **User** to have *changed* this file in **TFS**. (the last change date would be nice to have)

Though not directly related, as context information, Im using the following to get the latest from TFS based on a file's local path:

```
        var workspaceInfo = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(LocalPath);
        using (var server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(workspaceInfo.ServerUri))
        {
            var workspace = workspaceInfo.GetWorkspace(server);
            GetRequest request = new GetRequest(new ItemSpec(LocalPath, RecursionType.Full), VersionSpec.Latest);
            workspace.Get(request, GetOptions.Overwrite);
        }
```

thank you for any hints

Comment: Thank you very much Eddie and thanks DaveShaw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a simple code for your reference:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string tfsurl = "http://tfscollectionurl";
            TfsTeamProjectCollection ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(tfsurl));
            VersionControlServer vcs = ttpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
            string[] path = { "$/Path/To/Item.cs" };
            ItemSpec[] itemSpecs = ItemSpec.FromStrings(path, RecursionType.Full);
            ItemSpec itemSpec = itemSpecs.Cast<ItemSpec>().First();
            IEnumerable<Changeset> changesets = vcs.QueryHistory(itemSpec);
            Changeset latestchangeset = changesets.Cast<Changeset>().First();
            Console.WriteLine(latestchangeset.Committer);
            Console.WriteLine(latestchangeset.CommitterDisplayName);
            Console.WriteLine(latestchangeset.Owner);
            Console.WriteLine(latestchangeset.OwnerDisplayName);
            Console.WriteLine(latestchangeset.CreationDate);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IVersionControlStore.QueryHistory()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh985572%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get the Changeset, by default results are returned most recent first, and you can request just the top ` change, there's an overload to also get the changes in that changeset.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add what I found in case it might help someone else (it appears to work for me)

```
 var workspaceInfo = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(modifiedPath);

    TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(workspaceInfo.ServerUri);
    VersionControlServer vcServer = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();


    using (var server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(workspaceInfo.ServerUri))
    {
        var workspace = workspaceInfo.GetWorkspace(server);

        QueryHistoryParameters historyParams = new QueryHistoryParameters(modifiedPath, RecursionType.Full);

        historyParams.MaxResults = 1;

        Changeset changeset = vcServer.QueryHistory(historyParams).FirstOrDefault();

        string theUser = changeset.CommitterDisplayName;

        MessageBox.Show(theUser);
    }
```